# How do I shake things up?

Tags: live-from-bikini-bottom

I've been playing [Live from Bikini Bottom](http://www.nick.com/games/spongebob-squarepants-live-from-bikini-bottom.html) and have finished most of the items on my todo list.

There is one task I can't seem to complete: "Shake things up!"

[image: List of things to do]

At first I though I could succesfully shake by useing the arrow keys to tilt the island. This, however, only seems to have dropped a few more items.

I've also tried picking up all the characters and vigorously thrashing them about, but to no avail.

I feel like I've exhausted all options. **How do I Shake things up(!)?**

For reference here are all the items I've collected so far, though none of them seem to enable me to "Shake things up".

[image: Items collected]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To shake things up, press the space bar repeatedly or click the island base repeatedly. This will cause an earthquake, complete that task, and drop the final item:

> The Golden Krabby Patty, which oddly doesn't seem to do anything at all.